# Anyone can upload to unsigned preset of Cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

From the [document of Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload), if we want to upload images from browser/app directly to Cloudinary server, we need to use `unsiged preset` method, but which looks that anyone is able to upload to your account without any restriction, why is it like that, can't understand. Anyone can help?

Comment: An unsigned upload preset allows you to have client-side code which can send uploads without needing to contain your account's API secret to create a signature. Because unsigned uploads are, not all upload options are possible (for example, overwriting is impossible), and the upload preset must be pre-configured with the options which will be applied to the uploads, so you have full control over what is uploaded. With options like HTTP notifications, you can receive a server-side callback for each upload, making it 'async' prevent the resulting image URL from being returned to the client, etc

Comment: And of course, if that's still a concern for you, you can use signed uploads where all files require your API secret to be used to sign the upload; you can still use that with client-side uploads including the Upload Widget by sending the options that will be used to your server, validating them, creating the corresponding signature, then returning that signature to the client-side code for use when calling the API

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks Cloudinary is deliberately downplaying usage of signature method. Uploading from browser/app directly to Cloudinary with a signature issued by customer's server with its api-key for per-request should be the first class method,  but it is rarely described and they just mentioned the jQuery way, it's totally awkward, I'm giving up using Cloudinary.